How to download existing file on server with blazor wasm
Suppos I have a existing file ("export.xls") on "wwwroot/files" folder and I want to download it,
I tried to use MemoryStream like:
 await ms.WriteAsync(resFile.Content);
 var res = new FileStreamResult(ms, "text/csv;charset=utf-8") { FileDownloadName = "export.xls" };
 return res;

but it doesn't work.

Add more context and details. You ask about downloading but the code starts with a Write.  Which flavour of Blazor, do you use an API ?

You could test this link to download file from wwwroot.
<a href="files/export.xls" download="export.xls">Download</a>

So you could create a link and mock a click on it.
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime _js

<button @onclick="download">download</button>

<script>
    function download(path,filename) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = path;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
</script>
@code{
    private async Task download(){
        await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("download", "files/export.xls", "export.xls");
    }
}


We can't create script tag in blazor componenet.

@HoseinGhasemi Could you create scripts.js file in wwwroot folder? Then you could add<script src="scripts.js"></script> in the index.html. Also there is other way to import js file for isolation if you want.
